# Designing an attendance system using QR code with Firebase

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, qr-code

I'm doing a academic project. simply the idea is creating an Attendance system that goes like this:

1. The Teacher logs in to his account in the **website**.
2. Teacher selects a section.
3. Teacher generates a QR Code to let the students scan it to attend.
4. The Student Sign in into his account using an **android app**.
5. Students Opens the scanner to scan the QR Code.
6. The system marks the attendance of that student in that specific section and in a specific date.

here is my design of the firebase database that i'm using

```
db{  

    Teachers{
         "cEEbohuR2bK6opZJ1z5RoPrbbrx1":{ //auth uid  
              tchName:"Jason",
              tchID:"24123"
    }
    Students:{
         "GsBEVEtZ9CeqzztDWEQd9GluVJJ3":{  //auth uid
              studentName:"Mark",
              stuID:"37294"
}
    Courses:{
         "JAVA101":{  //courseID
              courseName:"Java Programing",
}
    Sections:{  
        "56345":{ //secID
         tchID:"24123", //acts like a foreign key
         courseID:"JAVA101", //acts like a foreign key
           Students:{
            "37294":{
               studentName:"Mark"               
       }
   }
}

    Attendance:{  
        "56345":{ //secID
           "1-8-2018":{ //auto generated date?
               "37294":{ //stuID
                  attended:"true" // sets to true after scanning the qr code
            }
          }
        } 
     }
  }
```

My idea of the qr code thing is when the teacher generates it the value in the QR would be the Section ID then somehow I need to merge it with student ID when the student scans it, after getting the two values I need to auto generate the date of the lecture
,so i would have **3 values(secID,stuID,date)** to insert it into the Attendance tree and make the **"attended" attribute sets to "true"**

Now my questions are:

1. is there any better way to design my DB?
2. is my qr idea above possible to execute or is there a better way?

Comment: If that system is intended to actually track attendance for any significant reason I see a potential problem of students taking a picture of the QR code and sending it to others who aren't there so they can check in.

Comment: I may add a time limit for the QR code later to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the instructor to retrieve the attendance list? The nested object you show above could be flatter if your needs were different. In Firebase, you need to create your DB structure after your views (e.g., what you will retrieve from DB to show to users). Nesting is strongly discouraged against and duplication of data is acceptable.

For example if I wanted users to read the list of attendees by choosing a  section ID and date, I would create a table like this:

```
Attendance:{
    "123456":                //section ID
       {"01-08-2019":        //date
           {"865768": true}  //student ID: attendance status  
       }
           }
```

I can retrieve the list of attendees using the reference:

```
`Attendance/${sectionID}/${date}/`
```

Or I can have a flatter list if I wanted my users to click on a student's ID and retrieve all attendance records by the student:

```
AttendanceRecord: {
     "865768": {     //student ID
     "LxLy1a":   {   //unique attendance record key
               date: "01-08-2019",
               sectionId: "123456",
               status: true
                }                       
                   }
```

If my app's views were different, I would have to structure my database differently so that data is easier to read from Firebase without going too deep into the nested object.

You must not be too afraid to duplicate your data. Change your database based on the views in your app.